Intuition of conditional expectation: Williams's take, applied to E[E[R | $\mathcal{G}$]] = E[R]
Let $(\mathit{\Omega}, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space. Take $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ to be any sigma-algebra. Be given an extended real-valued random variable $\mathcal{R}\colon \mathit{\Omega} \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ for which there exists an expected value $\mathbb{E}[\mathcal{R}]$, finite or infinite.

Def. A $(\mathcal{G}, \mathcal{B}(\bar{\mathbb{R}}))$-measurable extended real-valued random variable $f\colon \mathit{\Omega} \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is called the conditional expected value of $\mathcal{R}$ given $\mathcal{G}$ if, for all $G \in \mathcal{G}$, it holds that $$\int\limits_{G}{f\,\mathrm{d}P} = \int\limits_{G}{\mathcal{R}\,\mathrm{d}P}.$$

An argument via the Radon-Nikodým theorem and monotone convergence shows that a version of conditional expected value always exists, and that any two versions agree $P$-almost surely. The notation is $\mathbb{E}[\mathcal{R} \mid \mathcal{G}]$.
On the intuition behind the definition, David Williams in Probability with Martingales (1991) has the following to say:

An experiment has been performed. The only information available to you regarding which sample point $\omega$ has been chosen is the set of values $Z(\omega)$ for every $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variable $Z$. Then $Y(\omega) = \mathbb{E}[\mathcal{R} \mid \mathcal{G}](\omega)$ is the expected value of $\mathcal{R}(\omega)$ given this information.
/ Changed notation of random variable from $X$ to $\mathcal{R}$. /
(from Part B: Martingale Theory. Chapter 9: Conditional expectation. Section 9.3. The intuitive meaning. Page 85.)


Question: I do not quite understand this explanation by Williams. Could you expand on what it means? To make the question more precise, how can Williams's intuition be applied to rationalise the fact that $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathcal{R} \mid \mathcal{G}]] = \mathbb{E}[\mathcal{R}]$? (This fact is clear from the definition, taking $G := \mathit{\Omega}$).

One problem I think I have is the part “The only information available to you regarding which sample point $\omega$ has been chosen is the set of values $Z(\omega)$ for every $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variable $Z$”, specifically “the set of values $Z(\omega)$ for every $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variable $Z$”. To which set or sets is Williams referring?

It does not make sense that the set being talked about is $$U(\omega; \mathcal{G}) := \{\, Z(\omega) \mid Z \text{ is } (\mathcal{G}, \mathcal{B}(\bar{\mathbb{R}}))\text{-measurable random variable} \,\}. $$
It does not make sense because every constant function is $(\mathcal{G}, \mathcal{B}(\bar{\mathbb{R}}))$-measurable, regardless of what $\mathcal{G}$ is. So, for any elementary event $\omega \in \mathit{\Omega}$ and for any sub-sigmaalgebra $\mathcal{G}$, it would be that $U(\omega; \mathcal{G}) = \bar{\mathbb{R}}$. So it is hard to understand how this would encode "known information", because it would not vary with $\omega$ nor $\mathcal{G}$.
Neither does it appear sensible that the set being discussed is $$V(\omega; \mathcal{G}) := \{\, (Z, Z(\omega)) \mid Z \text{ is } (\mathcal{G}, \mathcal{B}(\bar{\mathbb{R}}))\text{-measurable random variable} \,\}. $$
This seems to give "too much information" about $\omega$, which I was not supposed to know. For example, say $(\mathit{\Omega}, \mathcal{F}, P) := ((0, 1), \mathcal{B}(0, 1), \mathrm{Leb}|_{(0, 1)})$ (on which every cumulative distribution function is realised via a random variable by Skorokhod's theorem). Then $ (\mathrm{Id}, \omega) = (\mathrm{Id}, \mathrm{Id}(\omega)) \in V(\omega; \mathcal{G})$. So I could pick from $V(\omega; \mathcal{G})$ the unique pair whose first coordinate is $\mathrm{Id}$, and get $\omega$ from the second coordinate of this pair.


The intent of this question is to focus on Williams's intuition as quoted above, and how the intuition could be used to rationalise the equality $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathcal{R} \mid \mathcal{G}]] = \mathbb{E}[\mathcal{R}]$. The question is not about other possible intuitions, unless explicitly tied to Williams's.
This question is not intended to criticise Williams's intuition.

Intuition is a personal thing that should not be formalized to death. Can you live with a wording that says "the only information availlable to you is whether the events in the $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal G}$ have occurred or not" ?

Let $(E,\mathcal F,\mu)$ be a measure spce. If $f$ and $g$ satisfy $\mu(f\mathbf 1_A) = \mu(g\mathbf 1_A)$ for all $A\in \mathcal F$, then $f = g$ a.e.-$\mu$. For the case of conditional expectation, $X = E[X\mid \mathcal G]$ a.s.-$\mu\vert_{\mathcal G}$. In other words, $E[X\mid \mathcal G]$ is the obvious or natural estimator for $X$ knowing only $\mathcal G$. If $X\in L^2$, then this can be made more precise by noting that $E[X\mid \mathcal G]$ admits the variational representation of the solution of $\inf_{Y\in \mathcal G}E|X-Y|^2$.

@KurtG. Thank you for your response. To give a slick reply: As the author published his intuition in a public textbook, this is no longer a personal matter. Also, there might be various intuitions which may or may not make sense to me. I hoped to make this question specifically about the wording Williams provides. Perhaps I should edit to make this restriction more clear?

@Andrew Since you used a general measure space in your comment: The result in your second sentence might not hold. When $E$ is singleton and $\mu$ is infinite. Then every pos. function will have the same integral (infinity) over measurable sets but the functions may also be different with measure infinity. For $\mathrm{L}^1$ the result holds. As for the second half about the $\mathrm{L}^2$ case, I have read about this intuition, but it isn't clear to me why it aligns with Williams's. I intended to make this question solely about Williams's take/intuition. I'll make this more clear, thank you!

Your question is clear but I find the premise that an author's intuition has to pass the scrutiny of every reader in such a formal way quite unrealistic to say the least. Be glad that Williams has done his best and made us think about it. Purely formal books are very dull.

@KurtG. I am grateful to authors that divulge their inner monologue to guide readers to enlightenment, and so too very much to Williams. Indeed, purely formal books lack in the "conversation dynamic" department. Yet there is a partial converse: if a respected author publicly gives their intuition but I am incapable of understanding their explanation, I feel foolish. Since this is a fairly old book, I continue to believe that someone has understood Williams's intuition much better than I currently do.

I think what Williams wants to say is: for a fixed RV $Z$ that is ${\cal G}$-measurable the only available information given to us is if the RV took the value $z$ , that is, the sets ${Z=z},.$  And that holds for any $z$ and any ${\cal G}$-measurable RV $Z,.$ He did not mean that we are given all possible values of $z$ (which is indeed $\overline{\mathbb R}$). What he meant was that we are given events in ${\cal G},.$ This is pretty close to my wording above. I believe Williams chose the RV picture because values of RVs are "physical" ...

... while $\Omega$ and its subsets is something completely abstract.
